# TigerVNC as service in 22.04 headless Ubuntu server fails to start

Tags: ssh, systemd, vnc, headless

I have set up TigerVNC on a headless Ubuntu 22.04 server in the cloud, so headless.

Launching

```
vncserver
```

as my sudo user works fine and I can connect via an SSH tunnel (although I cannot launch browsers, which is a different issue).

These are the contents of my **xstartup** file:

```
#!/bin/sh

test x"$SHELL" = x"" && SHELL=/bin/bash
test x"$1"     = x"" && set -- default

vncconfig -iconic &
"$SHELL" -l << EOF
export XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
EOF
vncserver -kill $DISPLAY
```

This is the content of **/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service**:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TigerVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
#Group=user
#WorkingDirectory=/home/user
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/user/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -fg -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When applying `sudo service vncserver@1 start` or `sudo systemctl start vncserver@1`

Syslog records the following:

```
Oct 16 12:03:25 server systemd[1]: Starting Start TigerVNC server at startup...
Oct 16 12:03:25 server systemd[1]: Started Session 25 of User user.
Oct 16 12:03:25 server vncserver[3049]: vncserver: Option 2>&1: Unrecognized!
Oct 16 12:03:25 server vncserver[3049]:   For further help, consult the vncserver(1) and Xtigervnc(1) manual pages.
Oct 16 12:03:25 server systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 16 12:03:25 server systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 12:03:25 server systemd[1]: Failed to start Start TigerVNC server at startup.
Oct 16 12:03:25 server systemd[1]: session-25.scope: Deactivated successfully.
```

I suspect there has been a change in the way recent versions of the software work, but I would appreciate some insight on the matter.

Comment: If it is in the cloud then someone is hosting it? Have you asked them if what you are trying to do can be done in this situation?

Comment: @David this is a virtual machine sitting on a datacentre. It is unlikely that the error error **Option 2>&1: Unrecognized!** is related to hosting.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a service file meant for Ubuntu 20.04, but it needs to be slightly different for Ubuntu 22.04.

This should work:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TigerVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
#Group=user
#WorkingDirectory=/home/user
PAMName=login
PIDFile=/home/user/.vnc/%H:590%i.pid
ExecStartPre=-/bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1"
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -fg -depth 24 -geometry 1920x1080 -localhost :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Take note of the changes to the `PIDFile` and `ExecStartPre` lines. [Source](https://bytexd.com/how-to-install-configure-vnc-server-on-ubuntu/)